# Finding PID coefficient for my PLL system

Tags: pll

I have a feedback loop as shown below. We are fixing the noisy YIG with a cavity resonator and feedback (shown in the attached paper and diagram below).
The phase difference between the signal is transformed into voltage that feeds the yig and changes the frequency of the YIG proportionaly with the voltage we enter.

Generally speaking if I use an amplifier as shown below, then from control theory I get P controller.

What if I want to create a PID controller for the error fixing, will it work better?

Could you please recommend how to make a good PID that will. From the diagram below I have three components. How do I know how to plan the PID properly for my system it has coefficients?

How do I decide what K_P K_I and K_D to create?

[image]

[image]